# How to manage efficiently ib in xcode for big projects

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

Can we use multiple separate views and integrate/call them on main view within a cocoa project?

Currently we are dropping all of our sub views and IB controls into a single view and making changes in IB is becoming unamageble now. When working on IB in xCode, it consumes 2.4 GB of memory. Please suggest a better strategy to organize IB views and controls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Absolutely. There are lots of examples of using several nib or xib files together.  I suggest you check out the [sample code at developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Sample%20Code).